# Returning the value using INDEX MATCH based on the latest date

Tags: excel

I would like to have the value populated (B1) when data is entered into A1 based on the latest date. I have no idea how to incorporate a max function together with an Index Match.

See screenshot below.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If those dates are really dates and no text, check function MAXIFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you have Excel 365 you can do it using MAXIFS:

> [MAXIFS
> Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883)

```
=MAXIFS(F2:F7;D2:D7;A2;H2:H7;MAXIFS(H2:H7;D2:D7;A2))
```

If you got an older Excel version, you can do it using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(D2:D7=A2)*--(H2:H7=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(D2:D7=A2)*H2:H7)))*F2:F7))
```

Comment: i am receiving an error #value!

Comment: how can i rectify this? have included the screenshot in the original post

Comment: Looks like those dates are strings and not real dates.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rectify the strings to dates!
2. Use MAXIFS or SUMPRODUCT

[image]

Formulas used to rectify strings to date:

```
=MID(A22,FIND(" ",A22)+1,3)  
=VLOOKUP(B22,$Q$81:$S$92,2,0)  
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A22,B22,C22)," ","."))  
=D22
```