# Countif, nestedif and sumproduct not able to populate the correct data

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, sumproduct

I need some guidance on this, have been trying to figure what is the issues for a few days now..

I have got 3 workbooks; export, current workbook and credit limit request workbook.

The logic are as follows:

1. if Business Registration data in both export and credit limit request workbook exist, perform following formula:

(1a)

```
IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(B1,[export.xlsx]Sheet1!E:E,1,0)=VLOOKUP(B1,'[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$B:$B,1,0),SUMIF([export.xlsx]Sheet1!E:I,B1,Sheet1!I:I)
```

else

(1b)

```
VLOOKUP(B1,'[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$B:$M,12,0),SUMIF(Sheet1!E:I,B1,[export.xlsx]Sheet1!I:I))
```

2. if Business Registration data does not exist in export but exist in credit limit request workbook with duplicate Business Registration id, perform following formula:

(2a) *previously gotten help on the sumproduct formula* - [1]: [Returning the value using INDEX MATCH based on the latest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423842/returning-the-value-using-index-match-based-on-the-latest-date/72445315#72445315)

```
IF(COUNTIF('[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$B:$B,'[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!B2>1),SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--('[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$B2:$B1000=B1)*--('[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$S2:$S1000=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--('[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$B2:$B1000=B1)*'[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$S2:$S1000)))*'[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$M2:$M1000))
```

else

```
VLOOKUP(B1,'[Credit Limit Requests (no existing SAP IDs).xlsx]No SAP ID'!$B:$M,12,0)
```

Formula 1a and 1b is working fine but formula 2a and 2b does not populate the correct data.

End of the day i would like to combine both formula 1 and 2 into a single cell as an nested if.

Comment: You have a lot of open questions by now. Are you familiar with accepting answers? For example, the one you refer to in this thread.

Comment: @JvdV , yes I am